# "Show Scroll Bars" Setting Changes Randomly

Tags: keyboard, mouse, preferences, macos

Throughout the day, my *"Show Scroll Bars"* setting which I manually set to *"When Scrolling"* keeps changing to either one or the other two alternatives: *"Always"* or *"Automatically"*.

I've been trying to track down what is causing that without success. At some point I thought it was a OS bug but I can't find any references and it affects both Monterey and Ventura.

The change is not immediate, and I can't find any patterns. Sometimes when the Mac wakes up, sometimes during continuous use. There is no specific time, no action or whatever.

The only software that I have installed that could affect it, in my opinion, is:

- Logitech Options+ and drivers for my mouse and keyboard
- Wacom tablet driver
- Karabiner-Elements

My first clue was to watch who opens the corresponding *.plist* file. If it is coming from a process, it should reveal it. However: I can't find the corresponding *.plist*. Where is this setting stored in Ventura? I could only find references to it on older systems.

If I found the file, or if the setting can be changed with `defaults`, I could also set a cron job to change back to my preferred setting periodically. Not ideal, but better than the constant random changes.

Is this setting actually accessible in a *".plist"* or `defaults` host? It should be if a process changes it. Has anyone faced something similar, or had any idea on how to track down what is happening?

Comment: Would changing the .plist ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist help you?

Comment: @DomenicoVitoScalera I have been trying this lately. No effect. It still changes randomly.

Comment: For me it resets to "Always" reliably after a restart. I have to set it back to "When scrolling" every time-

Comment: @chrismarx In a certain way, I'm happy to know I'm not alone. Although I'm sorry it also happens to you. Do you have any similar programs installed as cited above?

Comment: @sidyll hmmmm.... I do have Karabiner, I guess we might have a culprit...

Comment: @chrismarx I just uninstalled it. Let's see how it goes.

Comment: But I use Karabiner so I can type on two keyboards at once in a split keyboard setup, I can't lose that . Hoping it's not the reason, lol

Comment: @chrismarx After some days experimenting with and without Karabiner, I can confirm you it is not the culprit. That's good and bad news, in a way.